# nssm - Not installing the application path and its parameters

Tags: windows, windows-services, nssm

I tried running the below command in administrator mode to install nginx as service

```
nssm install ztestservice "C:\Stack\nginx\nginx.exe"
```

nssm is installing the service but there is no reference to the application path in the registry. i.e. no parameters are set. When I try to start the service shows error "cant start service".

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using nssm to run a php script.  I find if you run just:

`nssm install ztestservice`

nssm will pop up a window that lets you set all the other parameters.  Otherwise, you can set the parameters separately using the set command:

`nssm set <servicename> <parameter> [<subparameter>] <value>`

so:

`nssm set ztestservice AppParameters "C:\Stack\nginx\nginx.exe"`

However, watch out. On windows 2012r2 i'm experiencing an issue where it now hangs on the stop command so i'd watch out for that!

EDIT: You can also run `nssm dump ztestservice' will also give you a list of the available parameters
EDIT2: (Will i ever stop editing this?)`nssm edit ztestservice' to edit the service you just created, changing all params and having them set in the registry.